# Is $1105$ the only Poulet-number of the form $2^a+3^b$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, perfect-powers, pseudoprimes

> Conjecture : $1105$ is the only Poulet-number that can be written in the form $2^a+3^b$ with positive integers $a,b$

A Poulet-number is a composite number $N$ satisfying the congruence $2^{N-1}\equiv 1\mod N$

For $1\le a,b\le 1\ 500$ , the only Poulet-number is $1105$ which is even a Carmichael-number.

If $a=0$ or $b=0$ is also allowed , the composite Fermat-numbers are additional Poulet-numbers of this form. Are those the only Poulet-numbers of the form $2^n+1$ ? If yes , how can we prove this ?

Comment: Downvoter : Which context do you expect here ?

Comment: I "equalized" the downvote by an upvote :)

Comment: Is there any known connection between Poulet and Carmichael Numbers?  There aren't that many small Carmichael numbers, so this seems a bit of a coincidence.  Still...one example and all.

Comment: @lulu A Carmichael-number is always also a Poulet-number but not vice versa. In fact, I do not expect additional Poulet-numbers. I just am curious whether we can prove it here.

Comment: When you wrote the only Poulet number is $1105$, did you mean the only Poulet number *that can be written in the form*… ?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Of course. Isn't this obvious , since I wrote : "for $a,b \le 1\ 500$" and mentioned the expression in the question ?

Comment: @Peter In short, your questions about the integer coordinates of the surface defined by 
$$\displaystyle{2^{2^x+3^y-1}=1+z(2^x+3^y)}$$ or, equivalently, 
$$z=\dfrac{2^{2^x+3^y}-2}{2(2^x+3^y)}$$ In other words, a very difficult diophantine equation.

Comment: @Piquito Of course , this is a very difficult , if at all solvable question. The diophantine equation will be too difficult , but perhaps some properties of the Poulet-numbers can be used to solve the problem or at least to increase the search limit drastically.

Comment: @Peter: Good luck. Nobody has said that the problem is not interesting.

Comment: I don't think this is very helpful but I say it anyway. Finding another example, if it exists, involves considering very huge numbers.

Your example $N=1105$ corresponds to $(a,b)=(10,4)$. For $a\ge4$ one has 
$$N=3+16m\space  \text {for } b\equiv 1\pmod4\\N=9+16m\space  \text {for } b\equiv 2\pmod4\\N=11+16m\space  \text {for } b\equiv 3\pmod4\\N=1+16m\space  \text {for } b\equiv 0\pmod4$$